# Editing dIfferent types of objects using different controls in Wpf Datagrid Column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I need to create Wpf Datagrid binding from ObservableCollection with dozen Dictionary where string is name of property and object is the property value. Every object could be a different type it could be boolean (checkbox), string (textbox), CustomClassObject (combobox or textbox), integer (textbox) or an enum (ComboBox with every value from enum).

And it needs to be populated dynamically.

I am trying to figure out it from last week but it is just hard.

Do you have an idea how to create such as datagrid which will solve this problem? How to bind such as List of objects pulled from dictionary or just whole dictionary to datagrid to allow user easily edit it?

Should I use datatemplate with some converters if it is possible, which will return right Control with corresponding value for each object. Or I should create usercontrol which will consist bindable property object to which I will assign right control full field by each value and it will be bind to ContentControl?

I will be grateful for every hint.

Thanks

Comment: If you use the dictionary like you say, you could only have 1 row of data...?
Unless you are suggesting have a collection of Dictionaries!?

Comment: Yes, you are right I have collection of dictionaries. Thanks Glen

Comment: Is that necessary? Do you not know what columns there will be at compile-time?

Comment: Two columns: property name and property value. Populated from this collections of dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
public class MyObjectList : ObservableCollection<object>
{
    public MyObjectList()
    {
        Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Key1", 1));
        Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Key2", "Value2"));
        Add(new KeyValuePair<string, bool>("Key3", true));
        Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Key4", 1.5));
        Add(new KeyValuePair<string, MyEnum>("Key5", MyEnum.OPTION3));
        Add(new KeyValuePair<string, MyCustomClass>("Key6", new MyCustomClass(123)));
    }
}

public class MyCustomClass
{
    int value;

    public MyCustomClass(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("MyCustomClass is {0}", value);
    }
}

enum MyEnum { OPTION1, OPTION2, OPTION3 };
```

XAML:

```
    <DataGrid Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
        <DataGrid.DataContext>
            <local:MyObjectList/>
        </DataGrid.DataContext>
    </DataGrid>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks jstreet for answer but in this approach I think I want to able to edit those values. I only be able to show them on the screen.

Comment: As it is you can already edit all built-in types, like string, int, bool, double, possibly enum (didn't try). For any custom class, like MyCustomClass, you can use a PropertyGrid.